# My riddle at work

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A simple riddle about how I feel right now.

> One in name made up of two,
>
> The first with honey, jam or glue,
>
> second: paper, glass or ice,
>
> less of them would be nice...

Of what do I speak?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A stab ... One in name made up of two,

> spreadsheets

The first with honey, jam or glue,

> these are *spread*  - if so J. Siebeneichler excels

second: paper, glass or ice,

> these are formed in *sheets*

less of them would be nice...

> Save them ... it's noel time for Scroogey bosses making us Cratchity.

Comment: Spot on as always Tom.  +1

Answer (score 18):

Do you feel

> spread thin?

"honey, jam or glue"

> Things you spread

"paper, glass or ice"

> Things that are thin

"less of them would be nice..."

> Less projects.

Comment: Not bad but not what I've got in mind. +1

Comment: Ooh, this is brilliant. +1

Comment: This is actually very close.

Answer (score 4):

*The first with honey, jam or glue,*

> Sounds like STICKY - a property shared by all of these things.

*second: paper, glass or ice,*

> Maybe SHARP? You can get a paper cut, or cut yourself on broken glass, or maybe get stabbed with an icicle.

I'm not sure about how to put the two together though. You feel

> sticky and sharp at work? :-P

Comment: Can't decide whether sticky and sharp are good words for how I feel right now.  ...maybe.  But that's not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You feel:

> You feel flat-stick

One in names made up of two:

> One hyphen in a names made up of two.

Jam, honey, glue:

> Jam, glue and honey are all sticky

Glass,  paper,  ice:

> Glass, paper and ice are all flat surfaces

Nice to have less:

> Nice to have less clients

because:

> because if you take the l t s away from clients and rearrange it would be nice, also because you are flat-stick
>   Or maybe it's not that complicated and you just mean less work / tasks / projects

(not sure about this last line yet :))

Comment: You don't seem to be answering the last line...

Comment: @Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος  oh ok, thanks, this is my first day on the site and I didn't know the rules will think about it then

Comment: will change the answer to include the last line, but might change it again later after I think a bit more

Comment: I'm not feeling flatstick but +1 and welcome to the site. :)

Comment: @Brent Hackers Haha, but it seemed to fit so well with the clues, thanks!!!